# Tableau: Append two separate Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, tableau-api

Is there a way to append two separate google sheets sources in tableau?

Reason being is some of my sheets have exceeded the 10 million cells mark and I'm forced to use multiple sheets

The sheets have exactly the same column structure

Comment: I don't use this but their documentation seems to say yes: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm

Answer (score 0):

'Join' is not the same as append. 'Join' adds columns, based on a key field, while append adds rows. Tableau calls append 'union'.

https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_combine.htm